# Duvida no banner

Tags: javascript

Esse Banner esta funcionando corretamente, mas so queria entender essa conta: `(bannerAtual + 1) % 3` sendo q: 
'BannerAtual = 0' 
entao, (0 + 1) = 1 % 3 = 0,3333....alguem me explica porque estar trocando po valor = 1 que seria o proximo array?

```js
var banners = ["imagem 1.jpg","imagem 2.jpg", "imagem 3.jpg"]
var bannerAtual = 0

function trocarBanner(){
 bannerAtual = (bannerAtual + 1) % 3
 document.querySelector('.destaque_img').src = banners[bannerAtual]
}

setInterval(trocarBanner, 2000)
```

```html
<img class="destaque_img" />
```

Comment: Qual exatamente é sua dúvida? não ficou claro na sua pergunta

Comment: E tipo, como que esta funcionando? porque que esta trocando valor de 'BannerAtual' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O operador `%` não é divisão. Ele retorna o "resto" da divisão do primeiro número pelo segundo, isso quando o primeiro é igual ou maior que o segundo. Caso o primeiro seja menor, ele retorna o primeiro:

```
1%3 = 1 // 1 (primeiro número, à esquerda de %) é menor que 3

3%3 = 0 // resto 0 (3 dividido por 3 = 1, resta 0)

5%2 = 1 // resto 1 (5 dividido por 2 = 2, resta 1)
```

[Referências neste link.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp)

Comment: Entedi, 
Isso resumiu tudo "Caso o primeiro seja menor, ele retorna o primeiro", não sabia

Comment: @Sorezemartins Isso. Quando se tenta dividir um número menor por um maior, o resultado é zero e o resto é o próprio divisor (considerando que o resultado da divisão seja um número inteiro).

Comment: Eu entedi, revisei aqui a materia de matemática, muito obrigado pela explicação

Comment: Só uma correção: eu disse "divisor", mas na verdade é "dividendo".